# Tutorial for using Preferences menu item on macOS with Xamarin in Vs for Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin.forms, preferences, visual-studio-mac

I have done some research and it is all in Xcode with Swift.

I am using Xamarin.Forms/ Cocoa App for macOS on Visual Studio for Mac.

I can’t find clear instructions for hooking app preferences of any kind so that the Preferences menu in macOS is functional.

I have searched for two days now and can’t work it out.

---

I have also asked about using the `Settings.Bundle` [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/How-do-we-create-and-use-BundleSettings/1360465) on the Microsoft website.

Comment: Settings.Bundle is something that works only on iOS and it works there with Xamarin too.

Comment: @IvanIčin I wondered if that was the case. Yet I do not see an entry in VS for Mac to create the bundle. Must it be done through Xcode only? Although, iOS is a digression from the task in hand of macOS. It is my understanding I must create my own window and link it too the Preferences menu item (or use a plugin that offers the same).

Comment: You can create Settings.Bundle in VS, it is a simple folder nothing more than that. Regarding the preferences window it would be really complicated if you are after the full Xamarin.Forms solution. If you want to display a native window it should be a bit easier.

Comment: @IvanIčin I was thinking of just using a XAML plugin popup window. But since this would be only on the Mac I had not thought of a native window. I have even considered just adding a submenu to my main menu to let you override the language. This is all I need preferences for at the moment.